# If a user answers their own poorly worded question, should the answer be downvoted?

Tags: discussion

I ran across [this self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376700/httpclient-doesnt-work-on-xamarin-ios-release) today. It appears the user was genuinely trying to share helpful knowledge, which is [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and in my estimation the the answer was thorough, well written, and could very well help others. Yet it got hit by downvoters who (I'm just speculating) *may* have taken exception to the way the question was written, or simply didn't know that self-answering is allowed/encouraged. I expressed my opinions in the comments.

Would others concur that downvoting the *answer* is not the way to go here? Should the *question* be downvoted? Closed? Personally I'm more inclined to help the user ask a better question since I do believe there is value in the answer, but I'm curious what others think.

Comment: Vote on the answer on its own merits. If the answer is not helpful, vote it down.

Comment: However, everyone is free to downvote a post for any reason they deem fit.

Comment: There's not really a question in the question, is there? Think of it this way, it's one thing to share information but you still have to have a "question" that someone else could answer. To make that possible, the OP needs to edit the question so that others who would like to address the situation can do so in answers of their own. :)

Comment: @Catija I couldn't agree more

Comment: The question in your linked answer was too broad/opinion-based, and while the answer was reasonable in itself, it's funny that the author speaks to themselves in the third person. They also managed to ask and answer their own question within minutes(?)/seconds(?), judging by the timestamps. In any case, it seems this question/answer pair is receiving downvotes for additional and credible reasons beyond the phenomenon you're referring to.

Answer (score 6):

Simply evaluate the post as if it weren't answered by the author of the question.  If someone had asked the question:

> I've been struggling for a while now as my iOS Xamarin Release build seems to just hang when I try to to a HTTP Get or Post using the HttpClient. As it seems like there are a lot of people having a lot of different problems, I shared the outcome of my research below and a variety of possible solutions.

And someone else had provided an answer with some blind guesses as to what the person was struggling with, do you think that would make a good answer?

I certainly don't.

It doesn't matter if the information in the answer is technically correct or not (I don't know enough about the subject to comment on whether or not it's correct), it's not *an answer to the question*.  Of course, *it can't be, because the question is simply unanswerable*.  The question is woefully inadequate in terms of asking a question with a verifiably correct answer.

Not only that, but the answer is trying to answer multiple *wildly* different questions.  It's just trying to contain a grab bag of several different, unrelated, problems.  That's just not how the site works, doesn't make for a good answer, and again, *is unrelated to the fact that they're the author of a question*.  If you were to go to any question and post an answer that answered several wildly different, unrelated, questions, you'd probably find yourself attracting downvotes.  Potentially useful answers aren't useful when they're not posted to the question they're answering.

Just having a few random correct facts doesn't make an answer a good answer.  They need to be correct facts *that actually answer the question*, for it to be a good answer.

Comment: @ToddMenier So then *you* are the one who's letting the fact that this is a self-answered question color your voting of the post, rather than the users you're accusing of voting based on the author, rather than the content.  Yes, lots of bad posts *could* be good posts if they were edited into good posts.  They can be upvoted *once said edits actually happen*.  We don't vote on how useful a post *could be edited into*, we vote based on how useful it *actually is*, and right now, it's not useful.

Comment: @ToddMenier And no, we *don't* want people just trying to take guesses at entirely ambiguous and unanswerable questions in the hope that they get it right.  It doesn't create useful content.  We want questions to be edited, and clarified, such that *answerers can be verifiable correct without needing to guess*, and *then* for them to be answered.  That is what creates useful references sources.

Comment: This answer is unwelcoming™.